# VS 2015 solution throws null exception only on my laptop

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have several properties that look something like the following:

```
public bool Visible
{
   get { return SelectedInstance.BooleanValue; }
}
```

The Visible property is bound to a wpf control (MVVM) and works on all my other computers and used to work on my laptop up until I reset the os (win 10), fresh install of vs2015.

Now these properties are throwing the following exception.

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>    HResult=-2147467261
>    Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The exception seems to makes sense (SelectedInstance is in fact null) but why am I seeing this exception now and only on one computer after a fresh install of vs2015? The solution is over 3 years old. It runs fine when I use Start Without Debugging. It also run fine on three other machines (all using Win 10 and VS 2015).

Comment: It may be that the updated version of .NET (being used on your new laptop, 4.5) references SelectedInstance as a ``null`` object when it's in a certain state, whereas in the past it simply set it as an empty object? You may want to check what changes have been made to the WPF control that you are utilizing in recent framework updates.

Comment: You should provide more input. Which Version of .NET Framework are you using? Any updates for it you don't have on the old ones?

Comment: may be an issue with .NET Framework version

Comment: Smells like a race condition.  You never won until just now.  Why?  Who could possibly tell from this?  We can't see your application and its timings, when SelectedInstance (whatever the hell that is) is null and when it is not null, and when the property is read and when it is not read.  Obviously you need to null check it.  Do so.  If it causes side effects you can't fix then ask about that.